# ADs in contracted Android app

Tags: android

I've written a small android app for a client. The client now wishes to put ADs in this app. The client has NO programming skills at all, but apparently does have a Google Play developer account, as he was able to upload the .apk file to Google Play. I can add whatever code or keys necessary to the app, but since the client is paying the bills, whatever ad revenue the ADs generate, should go to him. Since I've never put ADs in any of the apps I've written, I need some basic information on how complex this would be, and how to do it, so that I can quote him an accurate figure on how much it would cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AdMob for Android Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) is a good place to start. It's really a trivial thing to implement.

> This guide shows you how to integrate the Google Mobile Ads SDK into a brand new app and use it to display an AdMob banner ad. *It should take you about **thirty minutes** to complete* and will give you a good sense of how the SDK functions within an app. If you're new to Google Mobile Ads, this is a great place to start before moving on to more advanced examples.

*Emphasis mine...*